# ibm blockchain platform [[{ code: 71, message: 'Authorization failure' }]]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to register a user in a blockchain network that is using hyperledger fabric in its version **2.5.3**, I was able to enroll the administrator user, I was able to send data, but when registering a user it shows me the following error
[[ { code: 71, message: 'Authorization failure' } ]]

The error occurs when trying to make the following register.

```
const secret = await caClient.register(
      {
        enrollmentID: "user",
        role: "client",
      },
      adminUser
    );
```

I already validated the authentication data of the administrator user and they are correct, I am using the ibp tool to create the hypereldger network.

To register the user I am using the latest examples from the official hyperledger repository

Answer (score 0):

Is your client connection profile file up to date i.e. is it correct for the latest running instance of the blockchain network. You will find that creating an admin will nearly always work, but the register user requires the ability to connect to the network. This has been my experience, so be absolutely sure that the current credentials are correct.